# HTML button press doesn't send call to socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I'm trying to connect an HTML page to Socket.IO. Although I have experience in Object-Oriented languages, web is new and pretty frustrating for me so far. I've got a socket.io server running, which can be called to from C# and receives responses accordingly. However, now I need to connect it to an HTML page, which isn't working.

I've tried applying code from these three sites:
[Socket.io emit button press to all clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501154/socket-io-emit-button-press-to-all-clients)
https://socket.io/get-started/chat
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_quick_guide.htm

However, none of them even display the "user connected" message, even when literally copy-pasted.

The JS code I've written is this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var client;

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');

    //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('A user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('SERVER_CONNECTED', function () {
        console.log('SERVER_CONNECTED');
        client = socket.id;
        io.sockets.connected[client].emit("SERVER_REGISTERED");
    });

    socket.on('MOVE_LEFT', function () {
        console.log('MOVE_LEFT');
    });

    socket.on('MOVE_RIGHT', function () {
        console.log('MOVE_RIGHT');
    });

    socket.on('SHOOT', function () {
        console.log('SHOOT');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.attach(4567);
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Socket IO Connection</title>
        <script>
            var socket = io();

            function ClickLeft() {
                socket.emit('MOVE_LEFT');
            }

            function ClickRight() {
                socket.emit('MOVE_RIGHT');
            }

            function ClickShoot() {
                socket.emit('SHOOT');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello world
        <button type="button" onclick="ClickLeft()">Links</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="ClickRight()">Rechts</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="ClickShoot()">PIEW PIEW</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without the `io.attach(4567);` my C# code doesn't find the websocket, however I get an io error if I try to use this port for HTML as well (`EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`).

So, to summarize; why doesn't the HTML connect / send data to the socket?

Comment: You have to use `socket.io client` on client side and you have to connect to server first. [npm socket.io client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Console in the browser's developer tools.

You should see an error telling you that `io` is undefined.

You missed this section from the tutorial you linked to:

> ```
> <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
> ```